# In Activerecord can you use a hash selector instead of a join query to find records through a belongs_to relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models - "Part" belongs_to "Category"

In this scenario is it possible to take this query:

```
Part.joins(:category).where("categories.name = 'cars'").first
```

And create a hashed variation of it? I've seen stuff like this:

```
Part.where(categories: {name: 'cars'})
```

However the SQL it generates for the two are pretty different. If (big if) I'm not doing anything wrong here, then why does the hash'd version not work in this case? And what are the relationships in which it is intended to work in?

In case it helps here are my models:

Category Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
end
```

Parts Model:

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed join() and first() methods in the second example. Use:

```
Part.joins(:category).where(categories: { name: 'cars' }).first
```

Comment: They need to give out "bonehead" points here. I think I just earned one. Thanks!